# Correlate two type parameters

Tags: scala, types, type-parameter, existential-type, path-dependent-type

Suppose, I have a sequence of operations, some of which depend on some of the results of previous ones. Something like this:

```
 type Results = List[(Operation[_], Any)] // ???
 trait Operation[Out] { 
   type Result = Out
   def apply(results: Results): Out
 }

 class SomeOp extends Operation[String] {
    def apply(results: Results) = "foo"
 }

 class OtherOp extends Operation[String] {
    def apply(results: Results) = results
      .collectFirst { case (_: SomeOp, x: String) => x } 
      .getOrElse("") + "bar"
 }

 def applyAll(
  ops: List[Operation[_]], 
  results: Results = Nil
): Results = ops match {
  case Nil => results.reverse
  case head :: tail => applyAll(tail, (head -> head(results)) :: results)
}

applyAll(List(new SomeOp, new OtherOp)).last._2 // foobar
```

This works, but `Any` in the result list looks ugly :( 
Is there a way around it? Can I declare it somehow to guarantee that second element of the tuple is the of the `#Result` type declared by the first element?

Comment: You can set `Results = List[(Operation[X], X) forSome { type X }]`, or simply introduce a new `case class Result[X](op: Operation[X], outcome: X)` instead of using tuples. But it won't help you to get rid of the `Any` in the line marked `foobar`. Are you sure that you want a list of ops with existential types in the first place? Because "sequence of operations, some of which depend on some of the results of previous ones" sounds suspiciously similar to a *monad*, and those are known to be implementable in a way that fits nicely with scala's type system.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I know what monad is ... but not sure what you are getting at here. `flatMap` doesn't quite work here, because my operation does not necessarily depend on the result of (just) the previous one (I need the entire list for generality).

Comment: Actually, there is no `Any` in line marked `//foobar` (that's just `Operartion[_]`), the `Any` is in the very first line, declaring `Results`. Changing it to `List[(Operation[X], X) forSome { type X }]` does not compile: `(head -> head(results)) :: results` fails with "found (Operation[_$1], Any) ...". 
I figure, the problem is that `X` has to be the same for all elements, which is not the case here ...

Comment: Yeah, it somehow infers `_$1` and `Any` instead of `(Op[t], t) forSome { type t }`. First part of my answer shows how this can be fixed by introducing a type variable `t` in the left hand side of the pattern match: a somewhat underrated feature of scala's pattern matching, imho.

Comment: I've added `existential-type` tag, that seemed closer to the question than the `path-dependent-type`, because there were some `_`s but no `p.T`-s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to get rid of `Any`. Here is the list of options I could come up with so far:

1. Use `forSome` to "correlate" result with the operation
2. Define a custom class that holds both operations and results
3. Convert the whole design from lists to monad

---

**The `forSome` solution**

The question title seems to ask exactly about the `forSome`:

```
(Operation[X], X) forSome { type X }
```

Here, the type variable `X` is bound by the `forSome` quantifier, and it guarantees that the tuples in your list can store only operations and outputs of matching types.

While it prohibits the occurrence of tuples like `(SomeOperation[String], Int)`, the instantiation becomes a bit cumbersome:

```
    val newResult: (Operation[Y], Y) forSome { type Y } = head match {
      case op: Operation[t] => (op -> op(results))
    }
```

The `t` is a [type pattern on the left hand side of the `match-case`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/08-pattern-matching.html#type-patterns) there. This is sometimes helpful for working with existentials, because it allows us to give the existential type a name, in this case `t`.

Here is a demo of how this can be used:

```
type Results = List[(Operation[X], X) forSome { type X }]
trait Operation[Out] { 
  type Result = Out
  def apply(results: Results): Out
}

class SomeOp extends Operation[String] {
   def apply(results: Results) = "foo"
}

class OtherOp extends Operation[String] {
   def apply(results: Results) = results
     .collectFirst { case (_: SomeOp, x: String) => x } 
     .getOrElse("") + "bar"
}

def applyAll(
  ops: List[Operation[_]], 
  results: Results = Nil
): Results = ops match {
  case Nil => results.reverse
  case head :: tail => {
    val newResult: (Operation[Y], Y) forSome { type Y } = head match {
      case op: Operation[t] => (op -> op(results))
    } 
    applyAll(tail, newResult :: results)
  }
}

println(applyAll(List(new SomeOp, new OtherOp)).last._2)
```

It simply outputs `foobar`, as before.

---

**Custom class for operations + results**

Instead of using tuples with complex existentials, it might be easier to
define a custom type to hold operations together with results:

```
case class OpRes[X](op: Operation[X], result: X)
```

With a corresponding method returning `OpRes` added to `Operation`,
everything becomes rather straightforward:

```
  def opWithResult(results: Results): OpRes[Out] = OpRes(this, apply(results))
```

Here is a full compilable example:

```
case class OpRes[X](op: Operation[X], result: X)
type Results = List[OpRes[_]]
trait Operation[Out] { 
  type Result = Out
  def apply(results: Results): Out
  def opWithResult(results: Results): OpRes[Out] = OpRes(this, apply(results))
}

class SomeOp extends Operation[String] {
   def apply(results: Results) = "foo"
}

class OtherOp extends Operation[String] {
   def apply(results: Results) = results
     .collectFirst { case OpRes(_: SomeOp, x: String) => x } 
     .getOrElse("") + "bar"
}

def applyAll(
  ops: List[Operation[_]], 
  results: Results = Nil
): Results = ops match {
  case Nil => results.reverse
  case head :: tail => applyAll(tail, head.opWithResult(results) :: results)
}

println(applyAll(List(new SomeOp, new OtherOp)).last.result)
```

Again, it outputs `foobar`, as before.

---

**Maybe it should be just a monad?**

Finally, the first sentence of your question contains the phrase

> sequence of operations, some of which depend on some of the results of previous ones

This seems to me almost like the perfect practical definition of what a monad is, so maybe you want to represent sequences of computations by `for`-comprehensions instead of existentially typed lists. Here is a rough sketch:

```
trait Operation[Out] { outer =>
  def result: Out
  def flatMap[Y](f: Out => Operation[Y]): Operation[Y] = new Operation[Y] {
    def result: Y = f(outer.result).result
  }
  def map[Y](f: Out => Y) = new Operation[Y] {
    def result: Y = f(outer.result)
  }
}

object SomeOp extends Operation[String] {
   def result = "foo"
}

case class OtherOp(foo: String) extends Operation[String] {
   def result = foo + "bar"
}

case class YetAnotherOp(foo: String, bar: String) extends Operation[String] {
  def result = s"previous: $bar, pre-previous: $foo"
}

def applyAll: Operation[String] = for {
  foo <- SomeOp
  fbr <- OtherOp(foo)
  fbz <- YetAnotherOp(foo, fbr)
} yield fbz

println(applyAll.result)
```

It prints

```
previous: foobar, pre-previous: foo
```

I've made the chain of operations one operation longer to demonstrate that an operation in a monadic for-comprehension of course has access to *all* previously defined intermediate results (in this case, `foo` and `fbr`), not only to the *previous* one.

Comment: The problem with the monad solution is exactly that I want to avoid hardcoding the operations. The idea is to pass a list into `applyAll`, rather than spelling every call out in `for` comprehension ... The list is quite large actually.

Comment: But, the `OpRes[X]` thingy seems to work (I could swear I tried that, and it didn't let me to add to the list with wildcard, but I guess, I mistyped something there).

Comment: @Dima You probably didn't have a method on `Operation` that returned an `OpRes`, and instead tried to instantiate `new OpRes` inside the `applyAll`, so it failed for the same reason as the first attempt with `forSome` that you mentioned in your comment under question. If you wanted to omit `opWithResult`, you would again need something like the `head match { case op: Operation[t] => new OpRes(op, op.apply(results)) }`-construction with type parameter `t` to instantiate `OpRes`. You probably tried something very similar, but then too quickly dismissed it as not-compilable/reparable.