# Confusion with path projections

Tags: scala, type-projection

Here is what I am trying to do

```
class Bar[P](val x: P) { type Foo = P }
class Baz[R <: Bar[_]](bar: R) { val x: R#Foo = bar.x }
```

The idea is to create `Baz` with a single type parameter, and have access to both types inside of it.

But this does not work :(

```
found   : Baz.this.x.type (with underlying type _$1)
required: _$1
```

It sounds like "underlying type _$1" is exactly what I want here, but that does not compile. 
Is there a way to do what I want here?

**update**

Perhaps, I oversimplified the use case.
Let's say, `Bar` is actually something like this:

```
trait Foo[T] { def doStuff(t: T) = ??? }
class Bar[P] extends Foo[P](val x: P) { type Foo = P }
```

and somewhere else I have a

```
 def fooX[T](x: T, foo: Foo[T]) = foo.doStuff(x)
```

and I want to call it from `Baz`:

```
 class Baz[R <: Bar[_]](bar: R) { fooX(bar.x, bar) }
```

It feels like it should work: `fooX` parameters will always be of the correct type. But it does not compile, and I can't think of a better workaround than to have two type parameters to `Baz`, which seems redundant.

Comment: I assume you have good reasons to avoid `class Baz[T, R <: Bar[T]](bar: R) { val x: T = bar.x }`? Also, are you sure that `_$1` is "exactly what you want", because it's a type you know nothing about, and you want to make it escape from under an existential quantifier. If `_$1` escapes, it corresponds to an unbound variable freely floating around, and that's not good.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin well, "the good reasons" are that I have a ton of classes like that, and lots of code using them, and I want to avoid having to type two type parameters everywhere, one of which is completely redundant.
I am not sure what is the problem with `_$1`, I updated the question, hopefully, it is a bit clearer now what I am trying to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you invoke `fooX(bar.x, bar)`, the compiler sees only:

- `bar: Bar[_]` which is the same as `bar : Bar[X] forSome { type X }`
- `bar.x : X forSome { type X }`, which reduces to `bar.x: Any`

and then it fails to prove that `Any` is the same as `X` in `forSome { type X }`. However, if you bind the unknown type to a variable `p`, then the compiler sees:

- `bar: Bar[p]`
- `bar.x : p`
- `fooX[p](bar.x, bar)` is applicable.

Therefore, this works:

```
trait Foo[T] { def doStuff(t: T) = ??? }
class Bar[P](val x: P) extends Foo[P] { type Foo = P }

def fooX[T](x: T, foo: Foo[T]) = foo.doStuff(x)

class Baz[R <: Bar[_]](bar: R){
  bar match {
    case b: Bar[p] => fooX[p](b.x, b)
  }
}
```

---

**Outtakes (pre-update attempts)**

Two snippets that attempted to solve the original question, maybe you find something helpful here:

```
class Bar[P](val x: P) { type Foo = P ; val y: Foo = x }
class Baz[R <: Bar[_]](val bar: R) { val x: bar.Foo = bar.y }
```

another way to tie `x` to `Foo`:

```
trait Br { type Foo ; val x: Foo }
class Bar[F](val x: F) extends Br { type Foo = F }
class Baz[R <: Br](val bar: R) {val x: bar.Foo = bar.x }
```

Comment: I don't remember the details, but this seems to be a somewhat related answer: [Correlate two type parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49477293/2707792).